# [CDPaymentMethodModel name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

```
 struct WithProfileMenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var selectedPayment = CDPaymentMethodModel()
HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "creditcard.circle.fill")
                    Text ("Payment Method")
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: PaymentPickerView(selectedPayment: $selectedPayment),
                        label: {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(selectedPayment.name ?? "")
                        })
                }

struct PaymentPickerView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: CDPaymentMethodModel.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors:[]
    ) var paymentList: FetchedResults<CDPaymentMethodModel>
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    @Binding var selectedPayment : CDPaymentMethodModel
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(paymentList, id: \.self) { payment in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedPayment = payment
                    print("DEBUG\(selectedPayment)")
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    HStack{
                        Text(payment.name ?? "")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(payment.bank ?? "")
                    }
                    .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting this error on the title when I add Text(selectedPayment.name ?? "") inside the WithProfileMenuView. What is the reason of this error?

If I remove Text(selectedPayment.name ?? "") then it works fine but I want to see selectedPaymnet on the list.

Comment: Apparently  `CDPaymentMethodModel` is a Core Data entity. In this context the default initializer `CDPaymentMethodModel()` looks pretty weird because usually you cannot create records of an entity without involving the managed object context.

Comment: so how should I initialize selectedPayment as empty

Comment: Try an optional.